# Is there a way I can create infinite closures in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

I was presented with question and I had no idea how to do it

add() - > returns 0

add(1)() -> returns 1

add(1)(2)() -> returns 3

add(1)(2)(3)(4)() -> 10

Basically it can go on

Comment: "Is there a way I can create infinite closures in JavaScript" Yes

Comment: how to do that in js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my one line solution if you love aesthetics

```js
const add = (val) => (val ? (arg) => (arg ? add(val + arg) : val) : 0);

console.log(add(1)(2)(3)())
```

For Readability:

```js
const add = (val) => {
  if (val) {
    return (arg) => {
      if (arg) {
        return add(val + arg);
      } else {
        return val;
      }
    };
  }
  return 0;
};

console.log(add(1)(2)(3)())
```

**Edit : Explaination**

**I'll try to explain it in a simple way**

lets break it down with a example add(1)(2)(3)()

So it happens like this

- `add(1)` is evaluated first
- `add(1)`  -> returns a function (say _add())
- `_add()` is a closure so it has access to the val variable (with value  1) and has its own parameter args with value 2
- `_add(2)` ->  calls `add()` again with the result of the addition (val + args)

**`add(1)(2)(3)()` becomes -> `_add(2)(3)()`**

- `_add(2)` checks if it has a parameter args and if it does then it computes val + args and returns add(val +args) else 0

**`_add(2)(3)()` becomes -> `add(3)(3)()`**

- add(3) -> _add()
- _add(3) -> val + args -> add(val+args) -> add(6)

**`add(3)(3)()` becomes -> `_add(6)()`**

- `add(6)()` -> returns _add()
- `_add()` this time no parameter so return the value

I hope I was able to explain, comment if you have any doubts, I'll try my best

Comment: Note that it won't be infinite. It will stop working when stack overflows.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the arguments through the variable `arguments`. Read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

I'm using a basic for loop, mostly for clarity, to show case it below.

```js
function add() {
  var sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     sum += arguments[i];  
  }

  /* Alternative loop
  for (let number of arguments) {
    sum += number;
  } */
  
  return sum;
}

console.log( add(1) );

console.log( add(1, 2) );        // returns 3

console.log( add(1, 2, 3, 4) );  // returns 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

```js
   function add(a){
 func  = function(b){
  func.result+=b;
  return func;
 }
  func.result = a;
  return func;
 }
console.log(add(2)(2).result);
```

Each sequential call returns the same function again. You can do it infinitely and access result as property of the returned function.